# Time manipulation by -1 month +1 day is still 1 month difference from start

Tags: java, time, java-7, jodatime

I would like to reach date that is -1month +1day, which should be 0month difference from start date.

Using joda-time 2.10:

```java
int day = 29;
LocalDate date1 = new LocalDate(new GregorianCalendar(2019, Calendar.JUNE, day).getTime());
LocalDate date2 = date1.plusMonths(-1).plusDays(1);
Months.monthsBetween(date1,date2).getMonths(); // returns 0 <- it's OK
```

**but the same code with input `int day = 30;` returns -1 which is bad**.

That looks like an inconsequence in Joda library.
That's a case: shift by -1month change date by shift month number and keep day number no greater than in input, but month-difference between dates are depend on day of month.

Do you know any alternative and working solution?

---

I have found JSR-310 with [ChronoUnit](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html) - that solves the problem, BUT it needs Java8. I would like to stay on Java7.

Comment: You could use the ThreeTen Backport, which makes the Java 8 Date and Time API available in Java 6 and 7.

Comment: [ThreeTen Backport home page](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (because the idea of @MCEmperor is excellent)

Comment: By the way, is there a reason you use `GregorianCalendar`, while you're already using Joda Time at the same time?

Comment: `GregorianCalendar` used only for separate day value provide. Input could be provide in any different way as LocalDate constructor consumes objects that represents datetime.

Comment: `ThreeTen` could be a solution as I can process it on Java7 - so thanks! But if the issue exists only in one specific case, then using additional library - that sounds like overkill.

Comment: Are you already using Joda-Time a lot? If not swapping one external library that doesn’t do what you want for another more modern external library that *does* do what you want would seem a pleasant deal in my eyes? Also it’s only until you upgrade to Java 8 or later.